# Seemingly Simple Conditional Won't Work?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, conditional-tags

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and trying to build a navigation menu where the current item has an extra class on it to let them know where they are.

**The entire structure in question. It's using ACF repeater fields:**

```
<?php if(get_field('main_nav', 53)): ?>
<?php while(has_sub_field('main_nav', 53)): ?>
<li><a 

<?php 

$link1 = the_permalink();
$link2 = the_sub_field('link_url');

if ( $link1 == $link2 ) {?> class="s4-secondary-nav-current" <?php } ?> 

href="<?php the_sub_field('link_url'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('link_text'); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Specific conditional:**

```
<?php 

$link1 = the_permalink();
$link2 = the_sub_field('link_url');

if ( $link1 == $link2 ) { echo 'class="s4-secondary-nav-current"'; } else {} ?>
```

What seems to be happening is that $link1 and $link2 just get printed in the HTML.

**Was also trying to do something like this that gets same results as above:**

```
<?php if ( the_permalink() == the_sub_field('link_url') ) {?> class="s4-secondary-nav-current" <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you using `the_permalink()` within the WP loop?

Comment: No, but it outputs fine into the HTML... I used the get_permalink(); as well. They both output in test code just fine seemingly.

Comment: Use get_the_permalink as documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/ . and pass in the post id. That will allow you to use the permalink value in a variable. I can't say much about the ACF function though.

Comment: the_permalink echo's at the location in which it's executed. You cant store the result of an echo, so you have to use get_the_permalink.

Answer (score 2):

Both `the_permalink()` and `the_sub_field()` are functions that do more than output a string or URL.

Try using`get_permalink()` and `get_sub_field` instead:

```
$link1 = get_permalink();
$link2 = get_sub_field('link_url');
```

Comment: well, that worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

`the_permalink` doesn't do what you think it does.

For example, this:

```
if ( the_permalink() == 'test' ) {
```

Is the same as:

```
echo get_the_permalink();
if ( '' == 'test' ) {
```

`the_permalink` doesn't return a value, and outputs it directly. Use `get_the_permalink` instead, and check what functions do before using them.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I'm newish on WP after years on another CMS.Is this the best way to apply the class to the current link on the nav?